# VLC DirectShow capture to use default audio device

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, directshow

I need to capture audio with VLC from the default capture device set for the system in Windows.  If I set the audio device in the capture dialog to "Default", it seems to capture from the first audio device in the list rather than the one configured to be the default on the system.

[image: VLC Capture Dialog]

Removing `:dshow-adev=` from the command line doesn't help either.

How can I get VLC to capture from the default system device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DirectShow framework does not use the settings specified by Windows for default devices, therefore changing your options from the Windows sound settings will not affect DirectShow.

VLC is actually just enumerating the devices on the system and selecting the first audio device it finds.  You can just select the specific device that you want to use from the drop-down, or alternatively you can disable the audio devices you don't want to use until the one you want is first in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that is good to know.  My root problem is that I will be launching VLC from another program, and there doesn't seem to be a way to get a list of devices from VLC.  I thought that by using the default device, this would be acceptable, but if DirectShow is using its own settings, then that won't work.  Do you know of a way to get a list of devices from VLC, over STDOUT or something?

Comment: I don't know of any way to enumerate device from the VLC command line.  However, FFMPEG does seem to have that feature:  http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/DirectShow  You could also look at [this Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18295499/94928) if you're looking to do it programatically.

Comment: Thanks, that question you linked to is also my question.  :-D  Yeah, it seems I'll have to do it programmatically outside of VLC.

Comment: heh.. sure enough it is.  If you are going the programatic route, you might take a look at [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) specifically the `DsDevice` class.  That should make it pretty easy for you.

Comment: Nice find!  Thanks.  That will definitely help.